# Find all the values that meet the condition in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to find a set of numbers that can meet certain conditions.
For example, find a set of words that can exist in the dictionary:

```
testlist = "I like sunny and I like cloudy"
testlist1 = testlist.split()
dictionary = {'like': 'love'}
```

Obviously 1 and 5 can meet the requirements, but printing in different positions will display different results. If the position is on the left, only one number is displayed:

```
for i in range(len(testlist1)):
    if testlist1[i] in list(dictionary.keys()):
        print(i)
print(i)
```

which is:

```
1
5
6
```

If I add a parameter, the result will be different:

```
for i in range(len(testlist1)):
    if testlist1[i] in list(dictionary.keys()):
        m = i
        print(m)
print(m)
```

which is:

```
1
5
5
```

How can 1 and 5 be in a list?

```
['1', '5']
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Just remove the last `print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_of_index = []
for i in range(len(testlist1)):
    if testlist1[i] in list(dictionary.keys()):
        list_of_index.append(i)
print(list_of_index)
```

Answer (score 2):

The Pythonic way to do this:

```
for i, x in in enumerate(testlist1):
    if x in dictionary:
        print(i)
```

Note that you can iterate lists directly (`for x in teslist1`) or use `enumerate` to iterate indeces and elements in parallel. Moreover, dictionaries have `O(1)`,  lists have `O(N)` membership test. So by converting the dictionary to a list, you are just being more verbose to be less performant.

If you want to collect the indeces, use a conditional comprehension:

```
inds = [i for i, x in enumerate(testlist) if x in dictionary]
inds
[1, 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have the last print?

In this code

```
for i in range(len(testlist1)):
    if testlist1[i] in list(dictionary.keys()):
        print(i)
print(i) # This one looks unnecessary
```

You printing 1 and 5 and after the loop finishes you printing the last value i ever got which is 6

In this code

```
for i in range(len(testlist1)):
    if testlist1[i] in list(dictionary.keys()):
        m = i
        print(m)
print(m) # This one looks unnecessary
```

you again printing 1 and 5 and after the loop finishes you print the last value m ever got which is 5.